# send domMutated

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estaba trabajando normalmente en un sitio y de repente noto que los `AJAX` ya no funcionaban mas, miro en la consola de Chrome y me dice `send domMutated`, probé con Firefox y lo mismo. No se que pasa, estas lineas de `domMutated` van saliendo cada rato sin hacer nada.

El `AJAX` que tengo es solo para enviar formularios, no hacen nada mas.
También la consola de Chrome hace referencia a un `index.js` el cual no existe, jamas he creado un `index.js`.

He probado desactivando el antivirus y nada, siguen apareciendo esos mensajes.

¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias, ¡saludos!

Comment: si hace referencia a codigo que no tienes incluido, prueba iniciando una sesion de incognito, o desactivando plugins. Tambien revisa que pasa si haces clic en la referencia de index.js y ve adonde te lleva. Puede ser un modulo exportado

Comment: Gracias , he visto en paginas como facebook y youtube que tambien aparece , por lo tanto descarto que sea mi codigo, pero bueno, tendre que ver que le pasa al navegador.!